# Surfaces are homeomorphic iff are diffeomorphic.

Tags: differential-topology, surfaces

I have read this statement in several places:
"Two surfaces are homeomorphic iff are diffeomorphic". I think the nontrivial implication follows in this manner: First, we triangulate the surface and then we smooth the resulting piecewise linear manifold, but I haven't found and well-written proof. Could you possibly give me a reference for the proof? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about a square and a sphere? Or you assume that both surfaces are smooth?

Comment: Could you give a reference where you've read it? [This page](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82126/homotopy-class-of-a-homeomorphism) has some references for something similar to your question.

Comment: See [this MathOverflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96670/classification-of-surfaces-and-the-top-diff-and-pl-categories-for-manifolds), which gives a list of references.

Comment: Ilya: Sorry, you're right, I assume smooth surfaces :)

Comment: anon271828, I just read that in lecture notes on the net and google books without proof, because of that I need an strong reference

Comment: david, thanks! :D

Comment: There must be more to it than triangulating and smoothing because 1.  All smooth manifolds are triangulable (due to Whitehead, I think) and 2.  There are smooth manifolds which are homeomorphic but not diffeomorphic.

Comment: @JasonDeVito indeed. I've read that it's necessary to use tools form differential topology.

Comment: @Ilya: what do you mean? A sphere and a square are not homeomorphic.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: that was a typo, I rather meant a cube instead of a square.